# How to remove Start/End Element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, openxml, xmlwriter

I have doubt sgmlReading/XmlWriting in c#, I'm writing startElement, EndElement with few conditional based.

If I don't want to write specific tag but I need inner XML, how to remove the tag?, Please help to solve this!

This is my example XML:

```
<BODY>
    <p><l>bla bla</li></p>
    <h1><p2>bla bla</p2></h1>
    <xyz>bla bla<p3>bla bla</p3>bla bla</xyz>
    <abc><p3>bla bla</p3></abc>
</BODY>
```

Here, I'm reading XML element one by one, if element name is 'xyz' and 'abc', I don't want to write the element name.

```
public class XMLWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    //if element name this is following strings, i don't want to write element name.
    public static string[] notAllowedTags = new string[] { "xyz", "abc"}

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        bool doWrite = true;
        string tagLocalName = localName;

        foreach (string name in notAllowedTags)
        {
            if (name == tagLocalName)
            {
                doWrite = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (doWrite)
        {
            localName = tagLocalName;
            openingElement = localName;
            base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
        }

        else
        {
            //base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
            //else condition i don't want to write element, if i keep empty, 
        }
    }

    //this is for write start element
    public override void WriteEndElement() { }
}
```

Comment: can you  put your XML file

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Please provide an example of what you want to produce.

Comment: K.B and Jim Mischel, i modified my questions, please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to remove all the elements from the xml leaving the html behind

you can make use of regular expressions for the same

sample

```
void test()
{

    string result = Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"</*(?<tag>.*?)>", MyMatchEvaluator);
}

private string MyMatchEvaluator(Match m)
{
    string tag = m.Groups["tag"].Value;
    string result = m.Value;
    switch (tag)
    {
        case "xyz":
        case "abc":
            result = string.Empty;
            break;
            //more cases if needed
    }
    return result;
}
```

result

```
<BODY>
    <p><l>bla bla</li></p>
    <h1><p2>bla bla</p2></h1>
    bla bla<p3>bla bla</p3>bla bla
    <p3>bla bla</p3>
</BODY>
```

in the above sample the regular expression `@"</*(?<tag>.*?)>"` is looking for a element by matching `<` at beginning, following some text and ending with `>` while matching the tag name via a tag

you can work on the expression and replacement for more complex replacements.

Replace method provide you to specify your own `MatchEvaluator` for even more sophisticated replacements

**XML Writer method**

as requested here is the way to use XMLWriter to achieve the same

```cs
    void test()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<BODY><p><li>bla bla</li></p><h1><p2>bla bla</p2></h1><xyz>bla bla<p3>bla bla</p3>bla bla</xyz><abc><p3>bla bla</p3></abc></BODY>");

        MyXMLWriter writer = new MyXMLWriter("c:\\out.xml");
        doc.Save(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }

    public class MyXMLWriter : XmlTextWriter
    {
        Stack<string> elementStack = new Stack<string>();
        public static string[] notAllowedTags = new string[] { "xyz", "abc" };

        public MyXMLWriter(string fileName)
            : base(fileName, Encoding.UTF8)
        {

        }

        public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
        {
            if (!notAllowedTags.Contains(localName))
            {
                base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
            }
            elementStack.Push(localName);
        }

        public override void WriteFullEndElement()
        {
            string tagLocalName = elementStack.Pop();
            if (!notAllowedTags.Contains(tagLocalName))
            {
                base.WriteFullEndElement();
            }
        }

        public override void WriteEndElement()
        {
            string tagLocalName = elementStack.Pop();
            if(!notAllowedTags.Contains(tagLocalName))
            {
                base.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
    }
```

result

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BODY>
    <p>
        <li>bla bla</li>
    </p>
    <h1>
        <p2>bla bla</p2>
    </h1>bla bla<p3>bla bla</p3>bla bla<p3>bla bla</p3>
</BODY>
```

if you do not want to see the `<?xml version="1.0" ... >` then add the following oveerride to your writer class

```
        public override void WriteStartDocument()
        {
            //skip <?xml version="1.0" ... >
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Purshpraj for quick reply, currently, i'm doing the same way, i don't want to by Regex, and replace method, i want to do by xmlwriter method

Comment: OK, let me try to bring the xml writer method for you.

Comment: Just checking out, if the updated answer is what you were looking for?